# Angular 9 Ivy disabled but get ERROR in document is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I migrated an Angular 8 library project to Angular 9.   In my root tsconfig.json enableIvy is false.  The library builds find and the unit tests pass.

When I start an app (also within the same library project) via "ng serve" I get the error "ERROR in document is not defined".   However, if I set enableIvy to true for the app in tsconfig.app.json then the app starts.

How come I can't start the app with Ivy disabled?

Comment: Need more info on error.

Comment: Angular would only report back "ERROR in document is not defined"." and nothing else.  I did track it down to an issue in one my library's secondary endpoint components.  This line in a .scss file was culprit:  @import "../../../../../node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css";.  If remove the import then the issue goes away.  Any ideas?

Comment: Tough issue, it's probably coming from webpack at build time. Try this delete package. Lock.Json then run npm ci